# Is there any way to access register on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, debugging

There is a command called `debug` in windows that can manage register and memory, like change the value in ax, etc, is there any similar tool on Mac OS X?

I find a man page of reg, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/reg.1.html, it seems to be the tool I am looking for, but I cannot find it in my os, I am using mac os x 10.10

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sven I am learning Assembly by read a book, there are tutorial about how to play register and memory on windows platform, something like irb for ruby, I don't have window box, so I am try to find replacement on mac os x, just want to play with that

Comment: You can always install the superb, free Oracle VirtualBox and put Windows on there without it messing up your Mac itself with Microsoft software.

Comment: Virtual machine is a way, but it is a little bother, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is compile a program that has the assembly you are interested in (either start with C or write some assembly code by hand if you want.)  Then run it under the debugger (lldb or Xcode.)  Set some breakpoints at places that are interesting to you, run the program.  Then when you hit the breakpoint you set, you can use `register read` and `register write` to poke at the registers, or `memory read` and `memory write` to poke at memory.

Comment: don't know xcode can do that, can you give me a little more detailed step by step work through  about this?

Comment: The simplest place to start is to make a New Project in Xcode (File->New Project).  Select the OS X Command Line Tool project.  Then put a breakpoint in the main.c source file that shows up,  hit the Build & Run button and you will stop at your breakpoint.  You can view the disassembly either using the lldb console (on the lower RHS of the debug window) or by choosing Debug->Debug Workflow->Always Show Assembly to see it in the Xcode window.  Then in the console you can issue the "memory read" "register read" etc.  You can find out how to use this with the built-in help command.

Comment: The next bit is to get more interesting assembly code to look at, which you can either do by putting in some C code and poking at what it resolves to, or if you know how to write assembly, then make a new .s file & have at it...